# Somar +1 Variável a cada objeto criado

Tags: java

estou criando uma classe Candidato, onde passarei um nome e um número do candidato.
Nela criei um vetor, para armazenar o número do candidato. Para que não que não aja um número de candidato igual.
Criei uma variável, aux e uma cont, para varrer o for e assim verificar se aquele número já possui. Porem, eu digito número iguais e ele não acusa, quebrei a cabeça e nada. Mandei imprimir as variáveis aux e cont e percebi que todas as vezes que crio um objeto, os valores sempre são iguais. Sei que é para serem iguais, porem eu queria saber uma forma de somar +1 a cada objeto criado. Para que varra o vetor e verifique se há número do candidato igual.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Candidato {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    private String nome;
    private int numeroCand;
    private int votos =0;
    private int num[] = new int[100];
    private static int cont =1;
    private static int aux=0;

    Candidato(){
        System.out.println("Digite o nome do candidato");
        this.setNome(s.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Digite o número do candidato");
        this.setNumeroCand(s.nextInt());
        verificarNum(this.getNumeroCand());

    }

    public void verificarNum(int n){

        if(cont == 1){
            num[cont-1] =numeroCand;
            aux++;
            cont++;

            System.out.println("Candidato cadastrado com sucesso!");
            System.out.println("_________________________________________________________________");

        }else{

            for(int i=0;i<=aux;i++){
                if(this.getNumeroCand() == num[i]){
                    System.out.println("Número válido, pois esse já é de outro candidato.");
                    while(this.getNumeroCand() == num[i]){
                        System.out.println("Digite o número do candidato");
                        this.setNumeroCand(s.nextInt());
                    }
                }
            }
        }




        /*for(int i=0;i<cont;i++){
                if(this.getNumeroCand() == num[i]){
                System.out.println("Digite um número válido, pois esse já é de outro candidato.");

                    }
                }else{
                    System.out.println("Candidato cadastrado com sucesso!");
                    System.out.println("_________________________________________________________________");
                    num[cont-1] =numeroCand;
                    }
            num[cont-1] =numeroCand;

        }
        cont++;*/
        System.out.println("Cont: " + cont + "aux: " + aux);
    }
```

Comment: Se é **um** candidato porque tem um vetor com números nele? Me parece que a classe está conceitualmente errada, aí tudo o que fizer estará potencialmente errado. Até dá para arrumar uma solução para o perguntado, mas será arrumar a seta de um carro que nem anda direito.

Answer (score -2):

Não pode ser o caso com o qual você esteja tendo problemas. Mas há um problema aqui:

```
 while(this.getNumeroCand() == num[i]){
                    System.out.println("Digite o número do candidato");
                    this.setNumeroCand(s.nextInt());
 }
```

O laço while só está fazendo comparação com o número no índice `i`, o que possibilita o usuário entrar com o número que já foi inserido e checado pelo laço `for`, ou seja qualquer número menor do que `i` dentro da array `num`.